# How to show that if $f$ is a solution for $y" + y = 0$ and the graph of $f$ passes contains 2 arbitrary points then f is unique

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose that $f$ satisfies $$y'' + y = 0 $$
>   And the graph of $f$ contains the points $(a_{1},b_{1})$ and $(a_{2},b_{2})$, with $$a_{1}-a_{2} \neq n \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
>   Show that $f$ is the only solution with these properties.

I know that two points would determinate a unique line. For example, if $y''=0$, then

$f= c_{1} + c_{2}x$ is the general solution;
If $f(a_{1})=b_{1}$ and $f(a_{2}) = b_{2}$, then $c_{2}$ might be expressed in terms of $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_{2}$: $$c_{2} = \frac{b_{1} - b_{2}}{a_{1}-a_{2}}$$

And $c_{1}$ might be expressed in terms of $c_{2}$, so both constants are specified by two points in the graph, which guarantees that the solution is unique.

Should I try the same approach to my problem?

Comment: I'd start by finding the general solution to $y''+y=0,$ yes.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is $y=a\sin x + b\cos x$ where $a,b$ are real numbers. We are told that $y(a_1) = b_1$ and $y(a_2) = b_2$. This implies that $a\sin(a_1) + b\cos(a_1) = b_1$ and $a\sin(a_2) + b\cos(a_2) = b_2$. We can solve this linear system for $a$ and $b$ provided the determinant is non-zero. We compute the determinant to be $\sin(a_1)\cos(a_2) - \cos(a_1)\sin(a_2)$. Which is equal to $\sin(a_1-a_2)$ be one of those identities. If $a_1 - a_2\not = \pi n$, then $\sin(a_1-a_2)\not = 0$, so that the linear system can be solved for $a$ and $b$ uniquely.